# How do I interpret error codes from FrontPage Extensions?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, error-handling, frontpage

**Wrong answer was autoselected by the stupid bounty system.**

I'm using front page extensions to interact with SharePoint Services 3.0 as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms443099.aspx).

In most samples I have seen the client simply looks for particular English strings in the result and uses that to determine if an error has occurred. However, I am writing an application which may be widely deployed and put on non-English language SharePoint servers so I would like to use the returned error codes instead.

Unfortunately, the documentation for the error codes is [very poorly defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms433540.aspx). It contains such gems as:

> Although many RPC protocol methods have unique error messages, most rely on a standard error message format to relay information if a method fails to complete properly.

Hrm, what would be this "standard error message format"...
and

> The status is the error code from
>   FrontPage Server Extensions for the
>   condition encountered. osstatus is the
>   error code from the operating system..

also sadly entertaining:

> In general, the codes are integer
>   values and the messages are text
>   strings that summarize the error.

but nowhere is a table which describes the possible content of these errors to be found.

It seems likely to me that the OS error code would be an HRESULT but I have no idea what to look for in terms of potential sources for SharePoint error codes. My only clue is that status=589826 seems to indicate that a file already exists.

**Wrong answer was autoselected by the stupid bounty system.**

Comment: I dont know if what you wrote is a tragedy or a comedy (in regards to the docs you posted). i hope you get the answer you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it refers to this list of "standard" system error codes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Hrm, I wonder if the both the status and the osstatus use "System Error CodeS"

Comment: Actually, I don't think these could be the answer. So Far I've found two codes: 

589826: //Filename Already Exists
and
1966082: //Write Access Denied

Neither is in the scope of those error messages.